# change the color of asp lixt box on focus

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

How to write `CSS` to change the color of `ASP list box` when user focuses on it. In my text boxes, I have used the below styling but it is not working for ListBox.

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    opacity: 1;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
```

How to change the color of the list box when user focuses on ASP List box?

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstFlat" runat="server" SelectionMode="Single" class="js-example-basic-single form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Text="single room" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="double rooms multi storey" Value="2" />
</asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work when you give it is's own class, like `StyledListBox`.

```
<asp:ListBox class="js-example-basic-single form-control StyledListBox">
```

Then some css

```
.StyledListBox:focus {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    outline: 0 none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```